# Troubleshoot SSH connection problem

Tags: ssh, fedora, troubleshooting

I am looking for tips on how to troubleshoot a problem with connecting to a new server via SSH.  I am trying to connect using private-key authentication, where SSH uses my local private key to authenticate, without prompting for a password, but running into problems with that.

When I run `ssh root@newserver`, the connection succeeds immediately, without prompting me for a password.  In contrast, when I run `ssh user@newserver`, the private-key authentication attempt fails and it prompts me for a password.  I'm stumped about why the latter fails.  What should I try, to debug this?

Things I've already tried:

- I've carefully checked `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` and `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys`.  Both are identical, and both contain my public key.
- I've carefully checked the permissions on `/root/.ssh` and `/home/user/.ssh` directories on `newserver`.  Everything seems fine, and in any case, the permissions are the same for both.
- I've tried logging in from two different clients, and see the same behavior on both, so I don't think it is client-specific.  I can log into other servers successfully from both of those clients.
- I tried running `/usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 2323` on the new server and then connecting using `ssh -p 2323 root@newserver` and `ssh -p 2323 user@newserver`.  Here's the brain-twisting part: when I launch `sshd` by hand from the command line, I'm able to log in (both to `root` and `user`) via private-key authentication, but when I try to use the system-standard `sshd`, I can only log in to `root` but not to `user` via private-key authentication.
- I've run `ssh -v`.  I don't see any enlightening messages: with `ssh -v root@newserver`, I get

  ```
  debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
  debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-dss blen 433
  ```

  With `ssh -v user@newserver`, I get

  ```
  debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/daw/.ssh/id_dsa
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
  ```

  Adding more `-v`'s doesn't lend any insight; with `ssh -vvvvv bingen.cs.berkeley.edu`, I get

  ```
  debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/daw/.ssh/id_dsa
  debug3: send_pubkey_test
  debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
  ```

  so no indication of why the attempt to log in via private-key authentication failed.

This is Fedora 21, openssh-6.6.1p1-11.1.fc21.x86_64.

Comment: This sounds like a permission issue on the server. The files in `~/.ssh` as well as that folder itself have to follow certain rules (ownership/permissions), if `StrictModes yes` is set in `sshd_config`. To diagnose issues in general follow my guide [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128910/5462).

Comment: Also, could you show us the output of `grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$' /etc/ssh/sshd_config |grep -v '^#'` in an edit, so we can see what may be missing/wrong in the `sshd_config` file?

Comment: What about the server logs? Is SELinux enforcing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think nlu has pointed into the right direction.

The generally better way to trace down ssh problems is by stopping the `sshd` on the server side and then start it with `$(which sshd) -d`.

That will give you more meaningful error messages in almost all cases.

Update: Sorry - you already did this.

There seems to be one difference between sshd on the cli and the service: SELINUX.

On the CLI it is not as restrictive. Do you have selinux enabled? If so - check the se-logs/settings!

Comment: S/he's doing that (3rd point) although I guess s/he meant to type `sshd` there. Also, stopping the main SSH server is a bad idea on a headless server. Just because *some* user has connection issues, shouldn't prevent *you* as the admin to access the machine. I.e. use an alternative port. Check out [this guide](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128910/5462). Also IIRC, output goes to the log for your command. With `-D` it goes to the terminal.

Comment: @0xC0000022L I did not read that third point. Right. But I remember having a similar issue with selinux enabled. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: nice catch. That could be a reason. Since I don't use Fedora most of the time, I would not have thought of that.

Comment: Nice catch, Nils!  You got it exactly -- it was SELinux.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the ownership and permissions of /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys too.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a SELinux permissions problem with files in `~/.ssh/`.  I copied the files from a backup stored on an external drive, where I guess they had received different labels, and they kept their incorrect labels.

I should have known.  When experiencing puzzling failures that could be permission issues, always check SELinux.

The fix: `restorecon -r /home/user/.ssh`.