# Allow null password for file transfer from Sunsolaris machine to linux mchine?

Tags: linux, ssh, cron, solaris, scp

I m trying to pull a file from a **Solaris** server to my **Linux** server and I did it successfully by using `scp`.I want to run this below command as a cronjob,  *How can I save password for this automation for Solaris to linux file transfer?*

```
scp -r root@serverA.com:/usr/abc/* /home/def/
Password:
```

But every time it prompt for password.
I have already generate a set of public and private ssh keys on my machine for my user with:

```
ssh-keygen
```

And copy my public key to the remote host:

```
ssh-copy-id root@serverA.com
```

**Note:** I successfully run it at `cron` when both servers are linux server. Facing problem for Solaris server to linux server.*Here my local server is linux and remote one is Solaris server.*

Comment: Run a copy of sshd on the Solaris server in debug mode and see what it says.  This and some other troubleshooting steps are in this question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180858/troubleshoot-ssh-connection-problem

Comment: what do you see in logs? If you try to connect and get rejected, server should store the reason for rejecting. If not, increase verbosity in `sshd_config`, restart `sshd` and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I trust you have had a look at this:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4557/sshuser-33/index.html

Also, see the man page for you ssh client, you might have to force protocol version 1.

For a start, from what I understand, it does not even work in interactive mode. try `-v` flags, start with one

`ssh -v root@serverA.com`
then, if that does not tell you anything

`ssh -vv root@serverA.com`

as a last resort:

`ssh -vvv root@serverA.com`

Note that I always found the issue using just one `-v`.

Answer (score 0):

If it works from command line with the keys, then one situation that I see is that you are running cron with another user than the one to pull the files.

you can change your command to:

```
ssh -i <ssh_private_key> -r root@serverA.com:/usr/abc/* /home/def/
```