# ssh from user1@host1 to user2@host2 gives "Too many authentication failures"

Tags: ssh, pam

In the past I've been able to ssh as one user (`user1`) to another system as a different user (e.g., `user2`).  So for example, let's say I'm on `host1` as `user1` and I want to  login to `host2` as a `user2`; I would use the following command:

```
ssh user2@host2
```

And this used to work, prior to today.

> To get this to work, I added the public key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) of the private key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa`) being used (on `user1@host1`) to `user2@host2/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Today, I'm getting the error **Too many authentication failures**:

```
ssh -v user2@host2
. . .
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa2
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa1
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
Received disconnect from 10.22.3.4 port 22:2: Too many authentication failures
Authentication failed.
```

I can successfully login as `user1@host2`; so this works:

```
ssh host2
```

So I know that `host1` and `host2`support ssh keybased authentication.

**(Q) What commands can I use to troubleshoot this?**

**(Q) What are common log files I can check to look for errors/clues as to why this is failing?**

**(Q) What are common reasons for getting the error `Too many authentication failures`?**

## What I've tried

### Reset login failures

In the past when I got this error, I would use `sudo pam_tally2 -u user2 -r` on the host `host2`.  This would reset the login failures count.  However, after running this command, the *login failure* count remains zero even though I get the **Too many authentication failures** error message.  So it appears that this error isn't actually counted as a login failure (at least not by pam_tally2).

### Double-check the public key is set properly

I've verified that the public key in `user1@host1:.ssh/id_rsa.pub` is in the `user2@host2:.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

### Double-check the permissions on the files are locked down.

I've verified that the permissions on the files are correct.

```
drwx------ # Dir: user2@host2:.ssh
-r-------- # File: user2@host2:.ssh/authorized_keys
```

### Searches on StackOverflow

Found this which is very similar to my question.

- [Troubleshoot SSH connection problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180858/troubleshoot-ssh-connection-problem) - My question is a little more specific in the error I'm getting is **Too many authentication failures**.

### Google searches for answers

I've tried Google search on [troubleshooting ssh login failures](https://www.google.com/search?q=troubleshooting%20ssh%20login%20failures&oq=troubleshooting%20ssh%20login%20failures) and got more hits than I can summarize here.  So there are a lot of potential issues.

- Found [https://docs.digitalocean.com/support/how-to-troubleshoot-ssh-authentication-issues/#:~:text=Make%20sure%20the%20authorized_keys%20file,properly%20configured%20for%20the%20session](https://docs.digitalocean.com/support/how-to-troubleshoot-ssh-authentication-issues/#:%7E:text=Make%20sure%20the%20authorized_keys%20file,properly%20configured%20for%20the%20session). - Lists several things to check.

*Googled for [common pam errors with ssh login failures](https://www.google.com/search?q=common%20pam%20errors%20with%20ssh%20login%20failures)* and found

- https://serverfault.com/questions/836559/pam-tally2-does-not-tally-failed-logins-for-failed-ssh-login-attempts

Still searching for answer

Comment: Have you tried to generate another key, for example  `ssh-keygen -t ed25519` as `user1` on `host1`  and copy the public key (`id_ed25519.pub`) to `user2@host2:/.ssh/` directory.  The permissions of the `.ssh` directory of `user2` should be `700`. Also please check the `SELinux` label of the directory using `ls -ldZ ~/.ssh`  of `user2`.  Maybe there are weird characters in your `.pub` file.  How did you copy it? Use i.e:  `sed -n l ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`  and see what line endings are being used.

Comment: I haven't tried to gen new keys (yet).  I checked the permissions of the `user2@host2:.ssh/` directory and it is `700` and SELinux label is `system_u:object_r:default_t:s0` but I have no idea what this means.

Comment: My belief is that the key is valid and I get "logged in" and then the `host2` server see's that this user has had too many authentication failures and drops the connection.

Comment: You can run `restorecon -vvRF`  on the `.ssh` dir. It won't hurt. Also try to pass -vvv to the ssh command when connecting to host2. And did you try the `sed` part?

Comment: I recreated the public key from the private key (using `ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/53553/how-do-i-retrieve-the-public-key-from-a-ssh-private-key), and now things work.  Now I am confused as to who changed the private/pub keys and when.

Comment: @ValentinBajrami, Thank you for taking time to offer suggestions.

Comment: I did run the sed command wasn't able to find out what it is supposed to tell me.  All lines except the last had backslash at end of line and final line had a dollar sign as last char of the line

Comment: Great. Glad you solved the  issue. Have a nice say! The line feeds with a dollar sign are correct