# Can't connect to the sshd in my unprivileged LXC guest. What to do?

Tags: sshd, lxc, userns

So you configured your unprivileged LXC guest, by defining

```
lxc.id_map = u 0 1000000000 10000
lxc.id_map = g 0 1000000000 10000
```

and of course assigning those subordinate UID/GID ranges to an existing user (`usermod --add-sub-uids ...`).

However, whenever you `ssh host` you get:

```
Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer
```

However, inside the guest you can clearly see that the `sshd` is running (e.g. with `lsof -i :22`).

What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### General troubleshooting advice for OpenSSH

First of all I refer you to [this short troubleshooting guide for `sshd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128910/5462) which I am using as a recipe time and time again.

#### The plot thickens

Only difference in this case, I used `lxc-console` to attach to the guest, logged in and stopped the running `sshd` and then started my instance on the default port 22. And then I connected from the host to the guest with heightened verbosity:

```
$ ssh -vvvvvvvv host.lan
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/joe/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/joe/.ssh/config line 2: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to host.lan [10.0.3.223] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/joe/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/joe/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/joe/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/joe/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/joe/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/joe/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/joe/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/joe/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "host.lan" from file "/home/joe/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ED25519 in file /home/joe/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer
```

Hmm, there's nothing enlightening in that output. Let's check the server side output of our connection attempt:

```
# $(which sshd) -Dddddddp22
debug2: load_server_config: filename /etc/ssh/sshd_config
debug2: load_server_config: done config len = 724
debug2: parse_server_config: config /etc/ssh/sshd_config len 724
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:5 setting Port 22
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:9 setting Protocol 2
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:11 setting HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:12 setting HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:13 setting HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:15 setting UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:18 setting KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:19 setting ServerKeyBits 1024
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:22 setting SyslogFacility AUTH
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:23 setting LogLevel INFO
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:26 setting LoginGraceTime 120
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:27 setting PermitRootLogin without-password
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:28 setting StrictModes yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:30 setting RSAAuthentication yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:31 setting PubkeyAuthentication yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:35 setting IgnoreRhosts yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:37 setting RhostsRSAAuthentication no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:39 setting HostbasedAuthentication no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:44 setting PermitEmptyPasswords no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:48 setting ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:51 setting PasswordAuthentication no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:63 setting X11Forwarding yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:64 setting X11DisplayOffset 10
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:65 setting PrintMotd no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:66 setting PrintLastLog yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:67 setting TCPKeepAlive yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:74 setting AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:76 setting Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:87 setting UsePAM yes
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: private host key: #2 type 4 ED25519
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-Dddddddp22'
debug3: oom_adjust_setup
Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 4 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.
debug3: fd 5 is not O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 8 config len 724
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: send_rexec_state: done
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 10.0.3.1 port 51448 on 10.0.3.223 port 22
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: Network child is on pid 558
debug3: preauth child monitor started
debug3: privsep user:group 101:65534 [preauth]
setgroups: Invalid argument [preauth]
debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
debug3: PAM: sshpam_thread_cleanup entering [preauth]
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug1: do_cleanup
debug3: PAM: sshpam_thread_cleanup entering
debug1: Killing privsep child 558
```

Pay special attention to the following the following lines from the above output:

```
debug1: Killing privsep child 558
```

indicating some issue with the privilege separation feature of OpenSSH (configuration directive `UsePrivilegeSeparation yes`), and:

```
debug3: privsep user:group 101:65534 [preauth]
setgroups: Invalid argument [preauth]
```

indicating that an attempt was made to change the effective GID of the process to 65534.

#### Reviewing the container configuration

Now have a look again at the stanzas from the container configuration file:

```
lxc.id_map = u 0 1000000000 10000
lxc.id_map = g 0 1000000000 10000
```

which tells LXC to create a user namespace ([userns](/questions/tagged/userns)) with 10000 IDs for both, group and user IDs respectively, starting at 1000000000. Inside that namespace, the UID 1000000000 becomes 0, i.e. superuser.

#### The solution

There are effectively two solutions to the problem:

1. fix the container configuration and allow at least for 65535 subordinate IDs in the mapped range, **or**
2. set the configuration option `UsePrivilegeSeparation no` in `sshd_config`

#### Background

The script `container-userns-convert` which is [hosted on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~serge-hallyn/+archive/ubuntu/nsexec) (checkout with `bzr branch lp:~serge-hallyn/+junk/nsexec`) and written by Serge Hallyn, one of the important contributors to LXC, and uses `uidmapshift` from the same repository, will assign only 10k subordinate IDs for the mapping by default.

This tripped me up. Normally I assign a block of 100000 IDs (as it's easier to read) or 65535 myself.

Comment: I know this is old, but this answer saved my bacon and was exactly what I needed to figure out what was going on. In my case, because I was mapping a group inside the LXC container, I hadn't left enough GID space for SSH to work in. Increasing my space up to the full integer limit fixed my issue.

Comment: Glad it helped. That's the point of posting this sort of Q&As and sharing knowledge :)