# Connection to host closed by remote host. Exit status -1

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sshd, key-authentication

i run an virtual ubuntu server with i have normally no trouble connecting to. However in the last 4 days i got twice `connection closed by remote host`. 
I have multiple accounts but with each i got the same result.
After a reboot i was able to login again.

This is what i get when the login is not possible

```
 ssh -vvv user@host_name
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "host_name" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to host_name [IP.IP.IP.IP] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to host_name:22 as 'user'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:23
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from host_name
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-c
ert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received

debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,dif
fie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.co
m,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,r
sa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-c
bc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-c
bc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.
com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.
com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,dif
fie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.c
om,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.c
om,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,h
mac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openss
h.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,h
mac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openss
h.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:eJMfyQRvAyYtV7qR3eZHoHJv4um5NlkZ6lqOM5+3/x8
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:23
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from host
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:24
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from IP.IP.IP.IP
debug1: Host 'host' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:23
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: user@local (0x5587cbcb1630), agent
debug2: key: user@local (0x5587cbcaf4f0), agent
debug2: key: user@local (0x5587cbcaf560), agent
debug2: key: user@local (0x5587cbcb1260), agent
debug2: key: user@local (0x5587cbcb12b0), agent
debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: user@local
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: user@local
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: user@local
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:sc7ESM4WTnxwcB1WLlNt0P34/j0U2c/SbDL2d9re7VA
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:sc7ESM4WTnxwcB1WLlNt0P34/j0U2c/SbDL2d9re7VA
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 53
debug3: input_userauth_banner
System is booting up.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to host ([IP.IP.IP.IP]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
#0 client-session (t3 r-1 i0/0 o0/0 fd 5/6 cc -1)

Connection to host closed by remote host.
Connection to host closed.
Transferred: sent 4028, received 2672 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 45293985.3, received 30046059.8
debug1: Exit status -1
```

To troubleshoot my problem

- i followed [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128894/ssh-exchange-identification-connection-closed-by-remote-host-not-using-hosts-d#128910) post and opened

  ```
  $(which sshd) -Ddp 10222
  ```

  and i was able to login with

  ```
  ssh -p 10222 user@host
  ```
- I am not using `hosts.allow` or `hosts.deny`.
- I have one account which has no associated ssh key. But even with typing the correct password i get the same error message.
- In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

  ```
   #MaxStartups #is not used
  ```

What other steps can i do to ensure that ssh is configured correctly.

Comment: @IjazKhan I also ran through that post, but i think i crossed out all the possibilities the answers provided and could not find a solution

Comment: Please paste your server auth/audit log related to ssh

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate of the other question. The other question is about an ssh failure before authentication takes place. In this question, the OP is getting a connection, authenticating, and starting a session. The session is just terminating right away.

Comment: @theDrifter According to the debug trace, the ubuntu VM is having trouble starting a shell for the ssh session. It's failing to create a new process, or to execute the shell program, or else the shell is exiting right away for some reason. If the problem is intermittent, I'd start with the possibility that the system is low on virtual memory.

Answer (score 2):

"This message means that the client got a TCP connection to the server, but the server immediately closed it before the SSH protocol could get started (the ssh_exchange_identification routine implements the version string exchange, the initial step of the protocol).
This usually happens because of a `libwrap` setting which prohibits the connection. Check the server log; if this is the problem, you will see messages like these:

```
SSH1, OpenSSH sshd1[15092]: refused connect from 192.168.10.1
SSH2 sshd2[15085]: Denied connection from by 192.168.10.1 tcp wrappers.
```

If you compiled the SSH server with `libwrap (TCP-wrappers)` support, check that the rules in the files `/etc/hosts.{allow,deny}` on the server host allow connection to the SSH daemon. An entry like this, for example, will allow connections to sshd from any source address:

```
sshd sshd1 sshd2 : ALL : ALLOW
```

The name on the left must be the `argv[0]` value of the running daemon, so if you've invoked sshd under another name, you'll need to use that. Also, the rules are order-dependent, so the rule just given might not work, depending on the other rules and their relative placement. See the `hosts_access(5)` man page for details on the `libwrap` rule syntax and semantics."

See:  [SSH FAQ](http://www.snailbook.com/faq/)

Also , please see this Entry at [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/384676/linux-closing-connection-after-successful-login) , very helpful answers.

Comment: This answer doesn't apply to the OP's problem. The OP is getting a connection, authenticating, and starting a session. His problem is that the session is terminating immediately.